# Protractor not launching Internet Explorer or Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Protractor is launching only chrome by default even if I configure the browsers to be internet explorer or firefox. I tried reinstalling the drivers again even that dint help.

**My config file:**

```
exports.config = {
multicapabilities: [{
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    'browserName' : 'chrome'
  },
  {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    'browserName' : 'firefox'
  }
  {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'version'    : '11'
  }
],

framework: 'jasmine',
shardTestFiles : true,
maxSessions : 3,
specs: ['spec.js'],
onPrepare: function() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
      browser.getCapabilities().then(function (value) {
        reportName = value.get('webdriver.remote.sessionid') + '_' + 
        value.get('browserName') + '_' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                savePath: '.test/reports/',
                screenshotsFolder: 'images',
                consolidate: false,
                consolidateAll: false,
                filePrefix: reportName + ".html"
              })
             );
        fulfill();
      })
  });
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000
  }
};
```

**Drivers used:**

- chromedriver_2.30
- geckodriver-v0.19.1
- IEDriverServer3.7.0

Comment: I tried running with a single capability of internet explorer even in that case it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with internet explorer was because the driver was not properly installed.
This command helped "webdriver-manager update --ie64"
And the other reason was silly.
The c in multicapabilities was small
Now this works,
multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName' : 'chrome'
  },
  {
    'browserName' : 'firefox'
  }
  {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'version'    : '11'
  }
],